# Access exportToPDF progress for Map Series using arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, export

When exporting a map series using ArcGIS Pro, the built-in export tool shows the tools progress as number of pages complete. This is helpful to know how much time is remaining on the export. Using ArcPy, one can use exportToPDF as described in the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/mapping/mapseries-class.htm).

However,it seems like there is no way to replicate the built-in tools progress update using ArcPy. So my script is forced to only update a message to the user at completion of the export. This isn't very helpful since the export could be on page 1 or 100.

Is there any documented way to replicate the built-in export tools progress updates?

The only way I can think to do it is to instead loop through exporting individual pages to a temporary directory, then combining at the end into a single PDF and deleting the individual pages.

Comment: I think this is essentially a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118406/tracking-progress-of-running-geoprocessing-tools-in-arcpy , except that the other question is for an old version of Desktop, not Pro.  But I think the answer is probably still the same.